# __iadd__ magic function issues

Tags: python, dictionary

The following is some code from a class called Container, which is intended to be
a versitile data value storage with extra capabilities that the built in types dont't
have. the `__iadd__` function, for whatever reason, makes `self` equal to `None`. However,
the `__add__` function seems to be working perfectly fine, and the `other` argument
is not affected. This problem is baffling me and any help is appreciated.

```
class Container():

    def __init__(self,list0,list1):
        self.list0,self.list1=list0,list1
        self.pairs=zip(list0,list1)
        self.items=dict(self.pairs)

    ...

    def __add__(self,other):
        dictionary=self.items
        other = other if type(other)==dict else other.items
        for k in other.keys():
            dictionary[k]=other[k]
        return dictionary

    ...

    def __iadd__(self,other):
        self.items=self+other

# >>> c2 = Container([11,12,13],['k','l','m'])
# >>> print container + c2
# {0: 'j', 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g', 8: 'h', 9: 'i', 11: 'k', 12: 'l', 13: 'm'}
#
# Note: at this time the container does not equal None.
#
# >>> container+=c2
# >>> print container
# None
```

Comment: `__add__` should return a valid instance of `Container`, not just the updated value of `self.items`. Similarly, `__iadd__` needs to update `self.list0`, `self.list1`, and `self.pairs`, not just `self.items`. (Alternatively, `list0`, `list1`, and `pairs` probably only need to be local variables in `__init__`, not instance attributes.)

Comment: @chepner ... I need `list0`, `list1`, and `pairs` in other functions that I haven't put here. I will try your advice though as to `__add__`. Thanks

Comment: ok that fix worked out... so if you could post that as an answer I can mark it as accepted.